# RVM- Multiple ruby versions for different projects on same server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I am configuring a new server for multiple rails 2.x/3.x projects, with multiple ruby versions 1.8.7/1.9.2 using RVM.
I want to know how to set a project to use particular version of ruby and another project to use another version of ruby?

Thanks,
Pravin

Comment: If you are using Passenger this might help http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/

Comment: The corollary question would be- What method are you using to start your servers?

Comment: Yes, it will be passenger for production

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your project directories are:

```
/var/www/project1
/var/www/project2
```

Let's move to the multiple rails version management:
Run the below commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties
sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
rvm install 1.8.7
rvm use 1.8.7 --default
ruby -v
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
gem install rails
rails -v
```

Now change directory to:

```
$: var/www/project1 rails s
```

Move to second project:

```
$: var/www/project2
rvm install 1.9.1
rvm use 1.9.1 --default
gem install rails
```

and finally start rails:

```
$: var/www/project2 rails s -p 3003
```